# Get Django username to log signals

Tags: django, logging, signals

I am experimenting with logging in Django. I would like to log each occasion of users saving or modifying data. In my signal handler code, I have something like this:

```
@receiver(post_save)
def post_save_callback(sender, instance, created, raw, using, update_fields, **kwargs):
logger.info(
    'Post-save called for %s. Created? %r. update_fields: %s',
    sender, created, json.dumps(update_fields)
)
```

I would also like to log the username of the user performing the data manipulation, basically—the currently logged in user. How can I get this username?

Answer (score 1):

As described in documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/) signals are useful when many pieces of code may be interested in the same events.

Is it that case?

If the data manipulation is performed in admin panel you can consider to override `log_change` method of `ModelAdmin` object and you can use `request.user.username` to get the username of current logged in user.

```
def log_change(self, request, object, message):
    logger.info('User %s changed user data %s. %s' % 
                (request.user.username, object, message)
    super(MyClass, self).log_change(request, object, message)
```

Keep in mind that ModelAdmin already log changes in admin log, documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#logentry-objects)

Comment: I am interested in logging all changes to the data, be it via the admin panel or via web-forms or REST. So I think using signals is the way to go, right?

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done. The current user is only available via the request which is not available when using `post_save`.
To achieve what you are looking for you can do one of these:

1. you can override **the save() method** on that model.
2. You can use a middleware to store the current user(see this [snippet](https://gist.github.com/mindlace/3918300) wich can add user created_by and modified_by foreign key refs to any model automatically)